# Show that $|A|$ divides $q-1$ for $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$ if $x^2-\text{tr}(A)x+1=0$ has distinct solutions in $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

This problem has been giving me a lot of trouble. Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field of order $q$. Let $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$, the multiplicative group of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$. Note that the characteristic equation of $A$ is $x^2-\text{tr}(A)x+1=0$. Show that if the characteristic equation for $A$ has distinct solutions in $\mathbb{F}_q$, then $|A|$ divides $q-1$, and if the characteristic equation of $A$ does not have any solutions in $\mathbb{F}_q$, then $|A|$ divides $q+1$.

A piece of useful information is the fact that $SL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$ has an order of $q^3-q$. Showing that $|A|$ divides $q\pm 1$ is equivalent to showing that $A^{q\pm 1}=I_2$, the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. I'm not sure where to go from here though. I get the impression this problem may involve field extensions as well.

Comment: what does $|A|$ mean ?

Comment: Perhaps the order of $A$ as an element of $SL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Comment: Yes, the order of $A$. Sorry, I see how that may look like cardinality.

Answer (score 4):

If the (distinct) eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lie in $\Bbb F_q$ then
$\alpha^{q-1}=\beta^{q-1}=1$.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are outside $\Bbb F_q$ then $\beta=\alpha^q$
(Frobenius automorphism) and $\alpha\beta=1$ (determinant).

Comment: I would like to add that, in the case where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $\mathbb{F}_q$, the assumption that they be distinct is quite important.  For example, let $g$ be a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ and $$A:=\begin{bmatrix} -1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\,,$$ then the order of $A$ is precisely $2p$ if $q=p^r$, where $p$ is  an odd prime natural number and $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, and clearly, $2p$ divides neither $q-1$ nor $q+1$.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't quite follow everything. Clearly $\alpha^{q-1}=\beta^{q-1}=1$ when $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_q$ since $\mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$ is a multiplicative group of order $q-1$, but I don't see why this implies $A^{q-1}$ is the identity matrix. I also fail to see how you got $\beta=\alpha^q$ from the Frobenius automorphism when $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_q^{alg}\setminus\mathbb{F}_q$ where $\mathbb{F}_q^{alg}$ denotes the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Thank you!

Comment: $\alpha^{q-1}$ and $\beta^{q-1}$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{q-1}$. If your quadratic polynomial is irreducible, then if $\alpha$ is a zero, then so is $\alpha^q$.

Comment: I see now that $\alpha^{q-1}$ and $\beta^{q-1}$ are eigenvalues of $A^{q-1}$. I had forgotten that the eigenvalues of the power of a matrix are the powers of its eigenvalues. However, just because the eigenvalues of $A^{q-1}$ are both $1$ does not mean $A^{q-1}$ is the identity matrix. For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues of $1$. Finally, I don't see how you determined "If your quadratic polynomial is irreducible, then if $\alpha$ is a zero, then so is $\alpha^{q}$". Thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually, I have figured out your claim that "If your quadratic polynomial is irreducible, then if $\alpha$ is a zero, then so is $\alpha^q$". If $\alpha$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial which does not lie in $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the field extension $\mathbb{F}_q(\alpha)$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Furthermore, because $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\mathbb{F}_q(\alpha)$ have the same characteristic. Using the Frobenius automorphism $\varphi$ you previously mentioned and the fact that it is the identity function over $\mathbb{F}_q$, we have

Comment: $0=\varphi(0)=\varphi(\alpha^2-\text{tr}(A)\alpha+1)=\varphi(\alpha)^2-\text{tr}(A)\varphi(\alpha)+1=(\alpha^q)^2-\text{tr}(A)(\alpha^q)+1$, so $\alpha^q$ is the other root and thus the other eigenvalue. This still doesn't explain, however, why $A^{q\pm 1}$ would be the identity matrix.

Comment: I have started a small bounty for this question.

Comment: @JulianBenali Because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct we can deduce that $A$ is conjugate (possibly in $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_{q^2})$) to the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\alpha,\beta$. Therefore $A^n$ is conjugate to the diagonal matrix with entries $\alpha^n,\beta^n$. The claims then follow.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, I see. So that gives us $A^{q-1}$ must be equal to the identity matrix in the case that $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_q$ with $\alpha\neq\beta$. However, this still doesn't imply that $A^{q+1}$ is the identity matrix in the case that $\alpha\notin\mathbb{F}_q$ since it is possible that $\alpha=\alpha^q$ (in which case $\alpha^2=1$), so my question remains unanswered.

Comment: I have figured the second case out. Assume $\alpha=\alpha^q$. Then because $\alpha^{q+1}=1$, we have $\alpha^2=1$. Since $\alpha^2-\text{tr}(A)\alpha+1=0$, we have $2=\text{tr}(A)\alpha$. If $\text{tr}(A)\neq 0$, then $\alpha=2\text{tr}(A)^{-1}\in\mathbb{F}_q$, a contradiction. If $\text{tr}(A)=0$, then we have $2=0$ which means $\mathbb{F}_q$ has characteristic $2$. But then we have $\alpha=1\in\mathbb{F}_q$ since $(1)^2-\text{tr}(A)(1)+1=1-0+1=0$, also a contradiction. So $\alpha\neq\alpha^q$ in the case $\alpha\notin\mathbb{F}_q$, completing the proof.

Comment: @JulianBenali If $\alpha=\alpha^q$ then the same holds for $\beta$, and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ (because $\Bbb{F}_q$ is the set of solutions of $x^q=x$ in some algebraically closed field). In that case the order is a factor of $q-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, that's right. The polynomial $x^q-x$ won't have more than $q$ solutions in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$, but because all $q$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ are solutions of that polynomial, an element in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$ satisfies $x^q=x$ only if $x\in\mathbb{F}_q$.